# Select Query with Count with more than three tables

Tags: mysql

I have following query

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post, comments WHERE comments.postid = post.id) as totalcom 
FROM post, category 
WHERE post.categoryid = category.catid
```

Then it returns entire table this is exactly what i needed but totalcom is showing same total to all post, it should show count of comments to the post and if result 0 then should show blank or null and anything else.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use *correlation* to the `post` table of the main query:

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM comments 
        WHERE comments.postid = post.id) as totalcom 
FROM post 
JOIN category ON post.categoryid = category.catid
```

**Note:** Always use modern, *explicit* `JOIN` syntax as in the above query, instead of old-fashioned *implicit* syntax.

Comment: This is amazing, you saved my time. Simply superb. No Words

Comment: @SukantParvate Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted, if it helped you solve your problem.